# How to calculate smoothing constant alpha in ExponentialMovingAverage?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, smoothing

I'm trying to use `ExponentialMovingAverage` on a time series, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to calculate the smoothing constant. I read that the appropriate value to use is one that minimizes the sum of squared residuals, but I don't find any tool to calculate this. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: According to documentation, the smoothing constant should be between zero and one.  If "sum of squared residuals" is the criterion you choose, you could apply `ExponentialMovingAverage ` with many values of the smoothing constant, compute the sum of squared residuals for each smoothing constant, and by interpolation obtain a reasonable estimate of the smoothing constant to use.  Unless the time series is enormous in length, performing this calculation should not be time-consuming.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I'm looking for a more exact estimate, but I'll try. Thanks

Comment: According to the documentation, the smoothing constant `1` causes `ExponentialMovingAverage ` to return the original list, in which case the sum of squared residuals is `0`, which certainly is the minimum possible.  However, this does not look very useful.